# What is the difference between "Home" and"House"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> [1] *  I'm going to my friend's home*
>
> [2 ]*   I'm going to my friend's house*

Which of the two sentences is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[house](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/house?s=t)

Less familiar.  Used when referring to a residence that is literally a house, bricks and mortar.  If someone rents and lives in a house then you are going to "their house", the structure in which they live.

[home](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/home?s=t)

Familiar and comfortable.  Use when referring to a family or friend situation.  If you live someone nice and have dogs or a fireplace then the residence is referred to as a home.  Home is where the heart is, home is familiar, home is where you go after work to relax.

So it depends on the context of the paragraph. If you are going to dinner with friends in a comfortable environment then they have invited you to their home, if it's more casual and you are just stopping by then you are visiting your friends house.